# Add subView behind items to UINavigationBar in iOS 11

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, ios11

In my `UINavigationBar` subclass I am adding a subView with `insertSubview(customView, at: 0)` in order to place it in the very 'back' of the `UINavigationBar`.

In iOS 10 the added subView will be added the Title and `UIBarButtonItems` as I want it, but in in iOS 11 it seems like Apple changed something because no matter what I try the `customView` will be placed every time in the front of the `UINavigationBar`.

```
//containerView
containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -(statusBarHeight), width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: frame.height + statusBarHeight)
containerView.clipsToBounds = true

insertSubview(containerView, at: 0)
```

I already tried changing the index.

Any idea how I should tackle that problem?

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Having same issue iOS 11 beta 9

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this. I solved it this way:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {  
        super.layoutSubviews()  
        for aView in self.subviews {  
            if NSStringFromClass(type(of: aView)) == "_UINavigationBarContentView" {  
                aView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: aView.frame.width, height: aView.frame.height)  
            }  
            else if NSStringFromClass(type(of: aView)) == "_UIBarBackground" {  
                aView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: aView.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Please extract the solution and post that as an answer. Do not simply link to other sites